# CSS: Aligning divs 2 on a line without using float

Tags: css

I am trying to avoid using float.  When I lower the width to 49%, they sit side by side but unevenly.  When I raise the width to 50%, each div sits on it's own line so I'm not sure why.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div {
    min-height: 50vh;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>Red</div>
<div>Green</div>
<div>Blue</div>
<div>Yellow</div>
```

Comment: If you put your divs all inline your code will works.
<div>Red</div><div>Green</div><div>Blue</div><div>Yellow</div>

Answer (score 0):

Because `inline-block` respect space character, in this case, each element puts a "character" space between the divs. Do avoid this there are [some tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) but I suggest you to use css grid:

```
body {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: CSS Grid would be better for more complex two-dimensional layouts though, this is a really simple one-dimensional layout, although it can definitely be done with Grid

Comment: grid still has some issues - i would recommend flex-box instead - allthough your solution would probably work in most cases

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline;` and `display: inline-block` uses text spacing as opposed to `display: block` which will position items more precisely.

By moving the divs to a single line, this forces the divs to have zero space in between them.

See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more information.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div {
    min-height: 50vh;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>Red</div><div>Green</div><div>Blue</div><div>Yellow</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use flexbox.

you would need to wrap your divs in another div width the class="container"

then you could do this

```
   .container {
      display: flex;           /* display side by side */
      align-items: center;     /* align vertically */
    }
    .container > * {
      flex: 1; 
    }
```

Comment: I’d rather not use flex-box...trying to accomplish with width and inline-block

Comment: flex-box is state of the art. inline-block is kind off a css hack.

Comment: you can still achieve what you want to achieve by not having any spaces or tabs between your divs. you need to write them right next to each other. inline-block interprets the space as a real space and causes your trouble.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to use inline-block make sure you write your html without any spaces.

this does **not** work:

```
<div>Red</div>
<div>Green</div>
<div>Blue</div>
<div>Yellow</div>
```

this does work:

```
<div>Red</div><div>Green</div><div>Blue</div><div>Yellow</div>
```

Comment: I never new this.  I didn’t think placing on a new line mattered.  Thank you

Comment: yeah thats the only case where it matters as far as I know.  It would be awesome If you could mark my answer as a valid solution.